# Inputs have very small height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I used bootstrap a lot of times before, but now in my GAE project I have a problem — the input elements have really small height. Buttons, for example, are OK:

[image]

HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="span6 pull-right">
         <div class="well well-small">
         <form>
            <input id="length" class="input-small" name="length" type="text" value="8">
            <br/>
            <input type="number" value="8">
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Generate">
          <!-- etc -->
```

Screenshot from dev tools:

[image]

Edit 2: Removed height:20px rule from bootstrap, now it's OK. But why it was there?

Bootstrap version is 2.2.1. Screenshot was made in Chrome 23.0.1271.95, Mac OS X 10.8.

Comment: If you inspect that element in the devtools of your browser, you will be able to see which CSS-rule that is the cause of this. You probably have some other CSS-rule that override the bootstrap properties.

Comment: I have only rules, defined by bootstrap.

Comment: Chrome on Mac has some issues with rendering inputs in fact my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303274/wierd-function-behavior-on-osx-with-google-chrome-browser was related to issues with chrome mac inputs. It doesn't directly relate to your question, but it is nice to know sometimes your not the only one seeing something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

to your document should fix the problem.

Comment: Exact (sudden) problem I had. This was the correct solution for me. Sometimes it's the little stuff you miss. :-)

Comment: It's the basic template explaned in the "getting started" document at bootstrap http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/getting-started.html :)

Comment: And is the correct declaration for html5 http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/syntax.html#the-doctype