# How to I make my '<input type="submit">' button higher

Tags: html, css, button, submit

I have a form on the homepage of the website I am working on with PHP plugged in. I have a 'submit' button at the end of my form but the button is not particularly big. I can adjust the width of the button using CSS however I cannot change the height of the button. Is there any way I can make my button larger?

This is the HTML for the button:

```
<form>
    <input type="submit" value="Log In"/>
</form>
```

This is the CSS:

```
input[type="submit"] {
   width:20%;       /*This works*/
   height:80px;     /*This does not work- the height does not adjust*/
}
```

Comment: It works.. http://jsfiddle.net/vueQH/ Those just aren't valid comments, therefore they are interfering with the CSS... A comment in CSS is `/* .... */` ... and now you have edited the question..

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me, even on the URL you gave me. Does it make a difference because I am working on an iMac?

Comment: Yes - quite possibly. What browser/version are you using..?

Comment: I am using the newest version of Google Chrome

Comment: Known issue on macs.. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009113/input-height-on-mac

Comment: Will my form still be posted to my PHP if I change the 'type' to 'button' on my HTML?

Comment: Yes, that shouldn't change anything in regards to PHP.

Comment: Even with "-webkit-appearance:button;" added to my CSS, the height still doesn't change!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<form id="login">
    <button>Log in</button>
</form>
```

Add the jQuery:

```
$( "button" ).click(function() {
    $( "#login" ).submit();
});
```

Accorting to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782317/inputs-have-very-small-height) post, adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` might solve your problem as well.

Comment: This works perfectly! However, there is no need for the jQuery, when the button is clicked, it automatically submits the form!

Answer (score 0):

Check if it is been overwritten by another class. Maybe a class below. Sometimes this happens if you are using external css frameworks . Like bootstrap , foundation..

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case. Thanks for your help anyway